# Get the most repeated value from columns of list other than zero in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a following data frame,

```
df1=
mac           gw_mac        ibeaconMajor  ibeaconMinor     
ac233f264920  ac233fc015f6  [1, 0, 1]        [1, 0] 
ac233f26492b  ac233fc015f6  [0, 0, 0]        [0, 0] 
ac233f264933  ac233fc015f6  [0, 1, 1]        [0, 2]
```

If all the values in a list(from the columns "ibeaconMajor" & "ibeaconMinor") is "0" it should return as "0" or else it should return frequently occurred non-zero values from a list as like below,

```
df1=
mac           gw_mac        ibeaconMajor  ibeaconMinor     
ac233f264920  ac233fc015f6  1             1 
ac233f26492b  ac233fc015f6  0             0 
ac233f264933  ac233fc015f6  1             2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise apply lambda function - first remve `0` values in list comprehension, get top values by `Counter` and add `next` with `iter` for possible add `0` if all `0` values - here in tuple for possible select first value of tuples:

```
from collections import Counter

cols = ['ibeaconMajor','ibeaconMinor']

f = lambda x: next(iter(Counter([y for y in x if y != 0]).most_common(1)), (0,))[0]
#alternative
#f = lambda x: next(iter(Counter(filter(lambda y: y != 0, x)).most_common(1)), (0,))[0]
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(f)

print (df)
            mac        gw_mac  ibeaconMajor  ibeaconMinor
0  ac233f264920  ac233fc015f6             1             1
1  ac233f26492b  ac233fc015f6             0             0
2  ac233f264933  ac233fc015f6             1             2
```